# how to change the chart UI when using Achartengine in android?

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

when using Achartengine for drawing a chart , the function of Achartengine library will just provide a intent, then you just need to  jump to the screen pointing by the intent ; yes .... this can be work perfect  .. However , the screen is so simple  and  the style of the chart screen is totally uncompatible with other screen's , and it seems that the Achartengine library doesn't provide any interface to change the chart UI ( not just the color of line or point), can any one tell me some idea to solve this issue...
  any help will be appreciated!

bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AChartEngine APIs actually allow you create views as well. This means that you can have a chart together with other UI components under the same screen. There is example code in the AChartEngine demo showing you how to do this.

Comment: my friend..you are right ...! i think i should use " charFactory.get****view " instead of " charFactory.get****intent " . i will test this method later , thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you apply an application wide theme through your manifest you will inherit some of them.  Things like background colors, etc.  Otherwise you have to specify your text/axis/line colors through code when setting up the intent.